# error when login to xamarin account from VS 2013

Tags: xamarin

[unhandled Activation Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9URoK.jpg)

I try to connect to my xamarin account from VS 2013 i can't, user name and password is correct and i loged in ffrom there website no problem

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2013 is not supported anymore. Use 2015 or newer.